# How to style Overlay on MapView

Tags: objective-c, ios5, mapkit, overlays

Image: ( http://photos.appleinsider.com/iOS5maps002.091111.jpg)

So can anyone let me know ..how to apply similar styles to our overlays (i mean to  the lines in the overlay)..

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to subclass [MKOverlayPathView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayPathView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKOverlayPathView) and define your own drawing behaviour..

> "If you subclass, you should override the createPath method and use
>   that method to build the appropriate path for the overlay. You can
>   invalidate this path as needed and force the path to be recreated
>   using whatever new data your subclass has obtained."

Comment: Can you provide with any simple example??

Comment: probably the method `strokePath:inContext:` is more important for your needs. you get the correct context there.. draw the path using coregraphics. You could also start one level lower and subclass MKOverlayView directly: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKOverlayView